# How to do conversion on one of the cell in SSRS 2010 while values in a group?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have one dataset with3 values as Currence, but the last value needs to be a number. How can I achieve that while all values in a group?
[image]

All in the Group
[image]

I need something like : 
`IIF(Fields!BookTotal.Value ="BINDS", then number, otherwice Currency)`
Can it be achieved with Format or FormatNumber?

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right track. You just need to provide the format strings.

```
=IIf(Fields!BookTotal.Value ="BINDS", "#,0;(#,0)", "c")
```

You can get it to generate format strings for you by setting the format in the textbox properties and see what it puts or the value of the `Format` property.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work, just place it into textbox property under custom.

```
=iif(Fields!BookTotal.Value ="BINDS","0;(0)","'$'#,0.00;('$'#,0.00);'-'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression in the FORMAT property of the cell:

```
=IIF(
Fields!BookTotal.Value ="BINDS", "0,000","$ 0,000")
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got this one, and it works

`=IIF(Fields!BookTotal.Value="BINDS", Format(Fields!BookTotal.Value,"##.##"),"C0")`